# How to split json.bz2 file randomly without iterating the file in python?

Tags: python, json, split, partitioning, bz2

I have a json.bz2 file over 50GB size. I would like to split file into partitions to run process in multithreads using python.

Could you please suggest me an ideal way to split json.bz2 file randomly (without reading / iterating) using python code?

Note: Process should not take hours to split.